# GDAL ZTSD compression not supported by Google Earth Engine (GEE)

Tags: gdal, google-earth-engine, compression

I am trying to upload a raster in GEE with ZSTD compression and it fails. Anybody knows why?

I have a small raster viirs_bin_090.tif and did `gdal_translate viirs_bin_090.tif viirs_bin_090_ztsd.tif -co COMPRESS=ZSTD`. The one with default compression (deflate) was uploaded and the other failed (see image below)

[image]

I checked with gdalinfo and confirmed that the compression was applied.

Now I am trying to upload it to GEE but got an upload error but there is no details as to why.

Comment: Probably Google are using an older GDAL without ZSTD support or an external libtiff not built against ZSTD in their GEE stack, but I don't know if / doubt that they publish those sort of details about their infrastructure.  Workaround by using a different compression.

Comment: Please provide the failed task id in text form.

Comment: @SimonIlyushchenko here is the failed task ID: PEYOYWUUUWUBHBODA2JTJDJF

Answer (score 4):

The libtiff and GDAL configs within Google have DEFLATE and LZW.  As of November 2021, LERC, WEBP, and ZSTD are not enabled.  You can do something like this for compression:

```
-co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9
```

You can also specify a PREDICTOR, which may help.  See here for more details on setting the PREDICTOR:

https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html